# WPF Window MouseLeave event not firing when cursor leaves window but remains over the main window

Tags: c#, wpf, mouseevent

I have a window shown via the `ShowDialog` command that I want to close when the mouse leaves that window. However, when the cursor leaves by any of the edges highlighted in green (see below) the `MouseLeave` event is not fired and the window isn't closed. If the cursor leaves by one of the edges highlighted in red the `MouseLeave event is fired and the window closes.

[image]

Window definition:

```
<Window x:Class="OutputDeviceView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        ResizeMode="NoResize"
        WindowStyle="None"
        ShowInTaskbar="False"
        SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"
        Background="Gray"
        KeyDown="Window_KeyDown"
        MouseLeave="Window_MouseLeave">
```

Event handler:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Handle the MouseLeave event. Close the window when the mouse leaves the window
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The object sending the event</param>
    /// <param name="e">The event arguments</param>
    private void Window_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        Close();
    }
```

The code that opens the window:

```
var outputDevices = new OutputDeviceView(this, _viewModel.OutputDevices, _viewModel.OutputDevice, PointToScreen(Mouse.GetPosition(this)));

if (outputDevices.ShowDialog() == true)
{
    _viewModel.OutputDevice = outputDevices.SelectedDevice;
}
```

Why isn't the `MouseLeave` event firing in all cases?

It has something to do with how the window is displayed. This window is displayed via the `ShowDialog` method, whereas the other windows which behave as expected are displayed using the `Show` method. (Thanks to [Mitra M](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5264680/mitra-m) for [pointing that out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62104338/wpf-window-mouseleave-event-not-firing-when-cursor-leaves-window-but-remains-ove?noredirect=1#comment109869307_62104338))

Comment: The combination of `ResizeMode="NoResize"` and `WindowStyle="None"` seems to be the problem. Have you considered using a Popup?

Comment: @Clemens - I hadn't until I started investigating this issue, but it's something I'm looking at now.

Comment: Grid or Border makes no difference for me. And would be totally unexplainable. It's certainly something else.

Comment: This behavior is just because of the modal window (ShowDialog), There is no difference between using a <Border>or a <Grid> in this case. you can test it by using Show instead of ShowDialog.

Comment: @MitraM Ah. That is the other difference between the windows. I was too focused on their contents, not the mode of display.

Comment: Found a couple other related questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39258393/ismouseover-trigger-doesnt-work-when-using-showdialog-and-borderless-window and https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b1990236-938e-4539-888a-4bfd8ccc3670/button-in-wpf-borderless-dialog-window-doesnt-change-from-mouseover-to-normal-state?forum=wpf